# javascript De-Obfuscate GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, deobfuscation

does anyone know a tool to de-obfuscate the javascript code here: https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/deferredjs/E274D5492EC18DBF7224C8750D1F62C6/10.cache.js

(this url changes, so I posted it in https://raw.github.com/gist/3749896/7a071a60fab01dfb89fb52f804f931ad246977f6/gwt)

I tried the one in https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset but it is not working.

basically I want to know how is the 'AVERAGE_TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES' got populated because it is not returned directly by ajax. from the page

[https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?_*u=1000000000&*_c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS)

Comment: your first link points to an error

Comment: it is https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/deferredjs/91B262019BC1E3A5D19C151A974361F0/10.cache.js now

Answer (score 0):

For GWT Deobfuscation you need the symbolMaps-files that contain the mapping between the obfusacted method names and the original method names. You will usually find them in the WEB-INF folder of your project. You will usually not find them on public websites.